# Visual C++ 2017 keeps rebuilding everything all the time

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

1. The project contains only C++ source. There is no custom-build item like a parser or lexer file.
2. the diagnostic output mentions something like:

   ```
   fileName.cpp will be compiled because the tracking log is not available.
   ```
3. There is another line in the diagnostic output, which I'm curious about:

   ```
   Source compilation required: input C:\<install_dir>\MSVCPRTD.LIB is newer than output .
   ```

Anybody any clue?

Comment: This problem is sometimes solved by deleting all temporary files while solution is not open. This includes those generated in project's and solution's folder (.user, .suo, .ncb). Try first with .ncb only. That's the most problematic one.

Comment: Also, make sure all your files have datetimes that are older than current datetime. If you changed the system calendar to some future date, and changed some file, and then changed back to current time, then this problem could happen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the source tree has been created using git running under bash_on_windows subsystem. There was a directory called AUX which cannot be accessed from within windows. Removing this AUX directory AND copying the entire tree to some other place resolved this problem.​